# 5 form elements present, but only 4 are saving to the database. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

> I am having a problem with my database. I am able to save all the elements of my form into the database but it is leaving out ":captcha" for some reason. :email, :first_name, :last_name and :user_message are all saving, but :captcha is not.
>
> HTML form views/pages/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, :class => "message_name_input message_input_default", :placeholder => " First Name" %>
      <br><br>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, :class => "message_name_input message_input_default", :placeholder => " Last Name" %>
      <br><br>
      <%= f.text_field :email, :required => true, :class => "message_email_input message_input_default", :placeholder => " * Email" %>
      <br><br>
      <%= f.text_area :user_message, :required => true, :class => "message_user-message_input", :placeholder => " * Write a message" %><br><br>

      <%= f.text_field :captcha, :required => true, :name => "captcha", :class => "message_input_default", :placeholder => " * #{@a} + #{@b} = ?" %><br><br>

      <div id="RecaptchaField2"></div>

      <%= f.submit "Send", :class => "messages_submit_button" %>

      <% end %>
```

> Pages Controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @message = Message.new

     @a = rand(9)

     @b = rand(9)
   session["sum"] = @a + @b
  end
end
```

> Messages Controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController


  def show
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if params["captcha"].to_i == session["sum"] && @message.save!
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@message).deliver_now
      redirect_to '/message_sent'
    else
      redirect_to '/'
    end
  end

    private
  def message_params
    return params.require(:message).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :user_message, :captcha)
  end


end
```

> Messages Migration

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
    t.string :captcha
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :last_name
    t.string :email
    t.string :user_message
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

> Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150822040444) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "captcha"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "user_message"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

end
```

> Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pages
  resources :messages
  resources :admins

  get '/' => 'pages#index'
  get '/new' => 'messages#new'
  post '/message_sent' => 'messages#create'
  get '/message_sent' => 'messages#show'
end
```

> **EDITED** Attempted this code, but instead of saving 4 elements, it executes the "else" statement and redirects as if it is not being saved at all.
>
> Messages Controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController


  def show
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if params[:message][:captcha].to_i == session["sum"] && @message.save!
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@message).deliver_now
      redirect_to '/message_sent'
    else
      redirect_to '/'
    end
  end

    private
  def message_params
    return params.require(:message).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :user_message, :captcha)
  end


end
```

Comment: try `@message = Message.create(message_params)` instead of `new` in your `messages#create` ?

Comment: I tried it, and instead of saving 4 elements, it executes the "else" statement and redirects as if the form is not being saved at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `name` attribute from here:

```
<%= f.text_field :captcha, :required => true, :name => "captcha", :class => "message_input_default", :placeholder => " * #{@a} + #{@b} = ?" %><br><br>
```

It happens because `name` parameter is generated by rails itself, and it's responsible to structure your query. Thus this erb line:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name %>
```

Will generate this html:

```
<input type="text" name="message[first_name]">
```

And when you submit form it will produce query like this

```
{ message: { first_name: 'value_of_input' } }
```

But you provided custom name that overridden default behaviour and produces requests like this:

```
{ captcha: 'captcha_val', message: { first_name: 'some_val1', last_name: 'some_val2', ... } }
```

Then you extract message params from `params`:

```
def message_params
  params.
    require(:message).
    permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :user_message, :captcha)
end
```

Finally you create message with this hash:

```
{ first_name: .., last_name: .., email: .., user_message: .. }
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for the quick response and accuracy of your answer!